# Getting details from the json file using AngularJS using search input

Tags: angularjs

My Goal:
        I want to search for the member details on input of the member id.
What i have don't till now?: 
        
My view is ready.I have create a service named myService which use $http 
        service to grab data from the members.json file.
My Problem?
        Instead getting the details of the particular id searched, I am getting 
        names of all members
What is want to ask?
        Who to get only the details of the searched member using his id.

```
  This is my view
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ0BP.jpg
  This is my code
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9tZp.jpg
  This is my json file
   {
    "member":[
    {   "Id":"1",
        "Name":"Amit Singh",
        "Dateofjoin":"21-03-2003",
        "Number":"934234334"
    },{
        "Id":"2",
        "Name":"Mohamad Aamir",
        "Dateofjoin":"21-03-2012",
        "Number":"934343434"
    }
   ]
  }




 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div>
 <form class="form-horizontal">
    <h2>Search for members.</h2>
    <input type="text" name="" class='form-control' placeholder="Member ID" 
     ng-model="searchId"/><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doSearch()">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div>   
    <p ng-repeat="x in data">
        {{x.Name}}
    </p>
    </div>


  </div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.controller('ctrl',
    ['$scope','myService','$log',function($scope,myService,$log){
        $scope.doSearch = function(){
             myService.getData($scope.searchId).then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                $log.info($scope.data);
                }); 
            };
        }])
    app.service('myService', ['$http','$log', function($http,$log){
        this.getData = function(memberId){
            return $http({
                url:"members.json",
                method:"GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json"

            }).then(function(response){
                var myData = response.data.member;
                return(myData);
            },function(response){
                throw response;
            });
        }
    }]);

    </script>
```

Comment: The relevant code must be **in the question, as text**. Not as a URL to an image.

Comment: Your service returns `response.data.member`, which is the array of all members. It doesn't do anything with the `memberId` that is passed as argument. So... why do you think this service should return only one member, idendified by the memberId? Why don't you change your code to look for the member identified by memberId, and returns that instead of the whole array? You need a loop. Or a call to Array.filter().

Comment: I know that it returns an array.I just wanted to know the different methods possible to do so. Thankyou btw :)

Comment: If all you have on the server is a static json file, the **only** possible way is to loop through the array and find the element that has the given ID. What else could you possibly do?

Comment: See data coming from function response  using console.log(myData); .See it contains the details or not.  @AmitPhartiyal

Comment: Thank you! New to angularJS :)

Comment: A real server would provide a RESTful API, allowing to pass the member ID in the URL, and get back a different response containing only the requested member (or a 404 is not found).

Comment: That's a lot of info. Can I use Postman to do so?

Comment: Postman is a REST **client**. Just like your code, it can send requests to servers. If you want a REST API, you'll have to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood the question here's the right answer:

```
app.service('myService', ['$http','$log', function($http,$log){
        this.getData = function(memberId){
            return $http({
                url:"members.json",
                method:"GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json"

            }).then(function(response){
                var myData = response.data.member.filter(member=>member.Id==memberId)[0];
                return(myData);
            },function(response){
                throw response;
            });
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

```js
  angular.module('TableFilterApp', [])
    .controller('TableFilterController', function($scope) {
      $scope.planets = [
        {
          name : 'Mercury',
          distance : 0.4,
          mass : 0.055
        },
        {
          name : 'Venus',
          distance : 0.7,
          mass : 0.815
        },
        {
          name : 'Earth',
          distance: 1,
          mass : 1
        },
        {
          name : 'Mars',
          distance : 1.5,
          mass : 0.107
        },
        {
          name : 'Ceres',
          distance : 2.77,
          mass :     0.00015
        },
        {
          name : 'Jupiter',
          distance : 5.2,
          mass :   318
        },
        {
          name : 'Saturn',
          distance : 9.5,
          mass :    95
        },
        {
          name : 'Uranus',
          distance : 19.6,
          mass :   14
        },
        {
          name : 'Neptune',
          distance : 30,
          mass : 17
        },
        {
          name : 'Pluto',
          distance : 39,
          mass : 0.00218
        },
        {
          name : 'Charon',
          distance : 39,
          mass :  0.000254
        }
      ];
    
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
  <title>Table Filter</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-app="TableFilterApp" ng-controller="TableFilterController">
 
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Average Distance</th><th>Mass</th></tr>
<tr><td><input ng-model="f.name"></td><td><input ng-model="f.distance"></td></td><td><input ng-model="f.mass"></td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="p in planets | filter:f"><td>{{p.name}}</td><td>{{p.distance}}</td><td>{{p.mass}}</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Here we use | filter for filtering the data in a table, but in your case we are finding data in li, use filter with ng-repeat but it shoulf be insure that from model,
 
And here we have dummy data, instead of getting it from angular services

Comment: https://code-maven.com/try/examples/angular/angular_table_filter_1.html